# Fire alert when user typed specific word into input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to fire an alert when user typed certain word into an input field... not when user clicked some submit button or anything... but immediately after the keyword is typed inside the field...

let's say the alert would fired immediately when "foobar" is typed into the following field:

```
<input id="password" name="password" />
```

is it possible to do that?

Comment: Set up an event handler on https://api.jquery.com/keydown/ and check the value of the input field for desired word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, easily:

```js
$(function() {
    var triggerWords = ['foobar', 'barfoo'];
    $('#password').keyup(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < triggerWords.length; i++) {
            if ($(this).val().toLowerCase() == triggerWords[i]) {
                alert('Alert!');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="password" name="password" />
```

This one handles multiple words. Here's a fiddle, too: http://jsfiddle.net/rnpykekx/

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed

```
jQuery('input#password').on('change', function(){
  if (jQuery(this).val() == "foobar") alert('bad password!')
});
```

This will catch the phrase foobar, but only after the user has stopped typing in the input.  Do you need to catch this before the user has stopped typing?

Answer (score 0):

Use an `onkeyup` or `onchange` (the latter will only fire when focus is removed) event to detect when the user changes something in the form (eg, typing), then search the input's value for the desired string (eg, with `inputValue.indexOf("foobar") != -1`, which will be true if "foobar" is in the string).

Note that this would end up alerting *every* time the user types something, even if they haven't just typed the specific word. One way around this would be to save whether you've already alerted (eg, alerting only the first time it's typed) or to keep track of the number of occurrences of the word, then alerting when that increases.